# how do I find the UTC offset from the TimeZoneID?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

We have built a drop down list of Timezones using the following built-in .net methods:"

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in timeZones)
        {
            SelectListItem li = new SelectListItem();
            li.Value = timeZone.Id;
            li.Text = timeZone.DisplayName;
            if (website.TimeZone == timeZone.Id)
            {
                li.Selected = true;
            }
            adminWebsiteVM.TimeZoneList.Add(li);        
        }
```

We then store the timeZone.Id (which is a string) in our DB. I chose to store the ID instead of the offset, because the offset changes with daylight saving time.

My question how to I get the UTC offset using the timeZone.Id property later? I cannot see any methods that allow for such a thing.

Comment: Thanks. My server is in UTC. So these do nothing since they work on server time. I am trying to work with the user's timezone which I should be able to calculate from the timezone offset. But since the timezone offset changes, I thought it would be prudent to get the offset as I needed it. So that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code for this method will do everything you want. I might put in an edit with some  brief example but I [think the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should suffice.

Basically you can use:

```
 TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
 TimeSpan offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime time);
```